# IP address range for examples in documentations

Tags: ip, documentation

Is there an IP address range dedicated to example in documentations ? (Like example.com for DNS)

Answer (score 9):

You mean like [RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737)?

The blocks are: 192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.0/24 (TEST-NET-2),
and 203.0.113.0/24 (TEST-NET-3)

Comment: For IPv6 use 2001:BD8::/32 as defined in [RFC 3849](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3849).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an IP address equivalent to "foo" and "bar", but I could recommend using the 10-net range since it is not routable and reserved for internal networks. Since you can use the entire 10.x.x.x set, it would prove perfect for just about all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

No, just use any of the [RFC 1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html) Addresses and you'll be fine. The other optino i've seen in documentation is the form: `1.2.3.4` and `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`